# Grep: Pulling multiple columns based off pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to parse a log file by pulling two columns (timestamp and url) where the file format is:
`1470700748 foo="narf1" url="http://narf2.com" bar="narf3"`

The column names are not guaranteed to be in the same order, except for the timestamp.

Getting the timetamp is easy enough:
`grep -Eo '^[^ ]+' test.txt` or
`sed 's/ .*//' test.txt`

I never been able to pull the url right, nor have I been able to pull them both at the same time.
`sed -n 's/.*url="\(.*\)".*/\1/p' test.txt`

The above works when there are no empty lines, so I'm also working on combining the sed command with:
`sed -e /^$/d test.txt`

most of the other SO posts dealt with fixed column orders and I wasn't able to get them working.  I tried many various permutations of grep, sed, awk, and cut.

has anyone done something similar? based on 1470700748 foo="narf1" url="narf2" bar="narf3", I am trying to get:
`1470700748 http://narf2.com`

Comment: [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output. Use the editors `{}` button to format it. Look around at other questions if you're not sure what I'm talking about.

Comment: Relevant FAQ entry: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

here you go...

```
$ grep -oP '^[0-9]+|(?<=url=")[^"]+' file | xargs

1470700748 http://narf2.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E -n 's/([^ ]+).* url="([^"]+).*/\1 \2/p' file
1470700748 http://narf2.com
```